# How to click on SVG element in WebdriverIO?

Tags: svg, automated-tests, cucumber, webdriver-io

I am using WebdriverIO + Cucumber and want to click on the SVG icon. I tried to perform click() with Xpath selectors like this:

```
$('//div[@class="unique-class"]//ul[@class="list"]//li[2]//div[@class="item-link"]');
$('//div[@class="unique-class"]//ul[@class="list"]//li[2]//div[@class="item-link"]//svg');
$('//div[@class="unique-class"]//ul[@class="list"]//div[@class="item-link"]//svg[@class="icon2"]');
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="unique-class">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">
       <div class="item-link">
          <svg class="icon1"></svg>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
       <div class="item-link">
          <svg class="icon2"></svg>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
       <div class="item-link">
          <svg class="icon3"></svg>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am new to testing please be aware of that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have not figured it out yet, svg in xpath doesn't work. You should use **//*[@class]** or **//*[@id]**

Example

```
$("//div[@class='parent']/*[contains(@class, 'svg-child')]")
```

You can trigger click on svg elements using SVGEvents.

```
clickSVG(xpath) {
    browser.execute(function (xpath) {
      var event = document.createEvent("SVGEvents");
      event.initEvent("click", true, true);
      var locator = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
      locator.dispatchEvent(event);
    }, xpath);
  }
```

Example

```
clickSVG("//div[@class='parent']/*[contains(@class, 'svg-child')]");
```